# How can I access the new password created from Firebase's sendPasswordResetEmail()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an Android Studio project using Firebase. Currently I store several User fields in the database under their email address. (Users > Email Address > (five different fields)). One of these fields is the user's password.

In my Reset Password workflow, I have Firebase send the User a reset password email. After the user goes through the link in that email, they successfully change their password and can now log in with their new password. My question is how can I grab that new password, and update the Users > Email Address > password field in my database right away? Currently this field is holding the old password that doesn't have any use any longer.

I don't believe we will need this field for the project, but I want to keep it updated for now in case another member on my team needs it. Thank you

Comment: First I've got to say, storing password into firebase databse is not a very good practice. But anyway, have you tried update the password value when user login in your android app? They would use new password right? Grab the value and send it to your database

Answer (score 0):

Do the same procedure as you would with a sign up form but retrieve the username object that is read and not allowed to be re-edited.

Then pass it through the object, validate it and write or overwrite it to the database.

Should you wish to keep their old password with the same username,  you can but it depends how complex you want this.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but my problem is how would I know when the user has accessed their email and filled out the form? Does firebase have documentation for that process?